# How do hacking groups get a license anonymously for threat emulation software like Cobalt Strike?

Tags: penetration-test, anonymity, defense, software

I've seen that a lot of hacking groups replicate techniques and attacks from red teams using software like Cobalt Strike and Powershell frameworks for offensive security and red teaming like Nishang and don't create custom malware like they used to do. Since you need to buy a license via credit card or check how do they get a Cobalt Strike license or any other software license without getting caught?

Comment: Not sure about Cobalt Strike but programs like Hex-Rays IDA are being cracked and pirated all the time. Reckon it's the same with other tools. 1 person buys em or manages to get a license through the workplace, and the cracking begins.

Comment: It's not clear to me that Cobalt Strike includes any watermarking which allows attribution from attack X to CS licensee Y to be made, in which case, there's no real barrier to buying and abusing. (and I say that as a legitimate user of CS).

Comment: Not to mention a black-hat hacking group could probably rustle up details of a hacked credit-card number.